# Memoization via template

Tags: c++, template, memoization, c++03

This is kind of follow up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573289/why-does-template-argument-deduction-substitution-fail-here) question on stack overflow...

I wrote the following to utilize memoization for functions that take a single parameter and return a value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class R, R (*Func)(T)>
R memoized(T in) {
    static std::map<T,R> memo;
    typename std::map<T,R>::iterator found = memo.find(in);
    if (found != memo.end()) { return found->second; }  
    std::cout << "not found" << std::endl; // only for demo
    R res = Func(in);
    memo[in] = res;
    return res;
}

double test(double x){return x*x;}
double test2(double x){return x;}

int main() {
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
not found
1
1
1

not found
1
1
1
```

It is a rather strong restriction that it works only for functions taking a single parameter, but thats ok for now. Is there anything else wrong with this approach?

PS: on purpose this is using only pre C++11

Answer (score 2):

I would change `memoized` to work with a functor type and use a traits approach to deduce the return type and the argument type.

```
template <typename Functor>
typename Functor::R memoized(typename Functor::T in) {
   using T = typename Functor::T;
   using R = typename Functor::R;

   static std::map<T,R> memo;
   typename std::map<T,R>::iterator found = memo.find(in);
   if (found != memo.end()) { return found->second; }  
   std::cout << "not found" << std::endl; // only for demo
   R res = Functor()(in);
   memo[in] = res;
   return res;
}

struct Test1
{
   using T = double;
   using R = double;
   R operator()(T x) { return x*x; }
};

struct Test2
{
   using T = double;
   using R = double;
   R operator()(T x) { return x; }
};
```

My rationale for using a functor is that it simplifies user code.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << memoized<Test1>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<Test1>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<Test1>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<Test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<Test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<Test2>(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hm.. the functions I want to use it for are partly legacy code. I think its a trade off whether it is worth wrapping them in a functor. However, I couldnt find out how to reduce the number of tempalte arguments on my own. Maybe some tempalte specialisation may help to accept both...

Comment: @tobi303. I think wrapping legacy code with a function is worth it. It obviates the need to repeat the type of `T` and `R` every time you call the function.

Comment: I was wondering if this also works across compilation units, ie if I can be sure that there will always be a single template instantiation for each function

Comment: @tobi303, are you worried about size of DLLs/EXEs?

Comment: no, I am worried about getting two instantiations with seperate static maps when it actually should be the same

Comment: @tobi303, in a single DLL/EXE, you shouldn't get separate maps. I will be surprised if that isn't true. I don't have a clear answer across DLLs/EXEs.

Comment: I would change memoized to work with both functions and functors.

Comment: @LokiAstari, do you mean "have two overloads"?

Comment: @tobi303, it's easy to reduce the # of template arguments if you can use c++11 and beyond, but you're restricted to c++03 right?

Comment: @RSahu No. If you generalize it enough it should work with either.